# Дата PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Нужно было сделать регистрацию пользователя. По итогам не получалось записать дату в столбец `user_date` с типом `date`.

Как это можно реализовать, и что писать в запросе к БД?

PS Сайт PHP + MySQL 8.0

Comment: Извиняюсь за свой вопрос. Понял что ставится дата системы на которой сайт

Comment: в запросе напишите `user_date = now()` без всяких дат из пхп

Comment: @teran: По моему вполне себе ответ. Не следует трогать php для получения даты, есть now().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом для данной задачи не нужно привлекать пхп. Если ознакомитесь с [документацией к mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html), то увидите, что при определении структуры таблицы вы можете указать значение столбца по умолчанию.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

тогда при вставке вы пропускаете это поле и оно автоматически получает нужное значение. Так же можно и менять значения инструкцией `ON UPDATE`.

Но и при обычной вставке обычно достаточно использовать функцию `NOW()`, то есть `insert into t1 (dt) values (now())` или `update t1 set dt = now()`. Пхп тут в целом не нужен.

Таким образом будут вставлены текущие значения времени на сервер СУБД. Если же вам требуется вставлять время, которое на сервере приложений (если оно вдруг отличается), или же пользовательское время то да, придется передавать значение как параметр запроса. Но поскольку в данном случае речь, кажется, идет о дате регистрации, то время сервера БД вполне подойдет